# Logic behind algebraic step in proof on orthogonality.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

**Theorem:** Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space and $T:V\longrightarrow V.$ Then

$$\langle{Tv, v}\rangle = 0 \iff T \equiv 0$$

***Proof:*** ($\Leftarrow$) Choose $u,w\in V$. Then $\langle{Tu, w}\rangle = \frac{\langle{T(u+w), u+w}\rangle - \langle{T(u-w), u-w}\rangle}{4} + \frac{\langle{T(u+iw), u+iw}\rangle - \langle{T(u-iw), u-iw}\rangle}{4}i$ which can be verified by computing the RHS. Note that each term on the RHS is of the form $\langle{Tv, v}\rangle$ for appropriate $v\in V$.

### My Concern.

I would like to know the motivation behind the algebra with inner products on the RHS. Where does this come from, how can I reproduce it myself, and why is it being used here?

Thanks.

Comment: Search up "polarization identity" I hope that's a good place to get you started.

Comment: One problem with this theorem is that it dos not say $V$ is an inner product space, but still assumes that an inner product exists. Vector spaces, complex or not, do not come with an automatic inner product. You have to define one separately.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The Chapter assumes every vector space is equipped with an inner product.

Comment: But you made no mention of it, so that information is missing from this post. As a general rule, you need to include all relevant information in your post. Admittedly, it is not a significant issue here, since the result to be shown is about inner products, so there must be one. But when I see something introduced without explanation, it always makes me very suspicious about what other relevant information was also not included in the post.

Comment: The only answer to your last question is obvious. It is used here because it demonstrates what was needed very easily. What other reason is there to ever include anything in a proof? And while it isn't the answer you want, what is ultimately the truest answer to your first question is that it comes from someone doing a lot of exploration on the properties of linear maps and inner products, particularly on whether $\langle Tv,v\rangle = 0$ can always be true without $T \equiv 0$, until they became familiar enough with the behavior to find this proof. And you can reproduce it by doing the same.